# Java 8 Stream - Reduce function's combiner not getting executed

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce, combiners

I am using a simple reduce method with three arguments viz. identity, accumulator and combiner.
Here is my code...

```
Integer ageSumComb = persons
            .stream()
            .reduce(0,
                (sum, p) -> {
                    System.out.println("Accumulator: Sum= "+ sum + " Person= " + p);
                    return sum += p.age;
                },
                (sum1, sum2) -> {
                    System.out.format("Combiner: Sum1= " + sum1 + " Sum2= "+ sum2);
                    return sum1 + sum2;
```

But what is happening is the Combiner is not getting executed. I am not getting the reason behind this.
Here is my output..

```
Accumulator: Sum= 0 Person= Max
Accumulator: Sum= 18 Person= Peter
Accumulator: Sum= 41 Person= Pamela
Accumulator: Sum= 64 Person= David
Accumulator: Sum= 76 Person= Pam
```

However, There was no compilation error and no exception and my output is exactly right, the same what i had expected. But did not get why the combiner not executed.

Comment: As a side note, `return sum += p.age;` is a misleading statement. The `+=` operator modifies the variable to its left, but since `sum` is just a lambda parameter, this modification has no effect. Since only the returned sum matters, the statement should be `return sum + p.age;`, so without the printing statement, the entire lambda expression could be `(sum, p) -> sum + p.age`. Still, `.mapToInt(p -> p.age).sum()` is cleaner and more efficient than the three-arg `reduce`.

Comment: "The combiner is necessary in parallel reductions, where the input is partitioned, a partial accumulation computed for each partition, and then the partial results are combined to produce a final result." You could have found this statement in the stream package [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combiner gets executed only for a parallel stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parallelStream` instead of `stream` if you are going to use combiner