# Using parallel stream in Java but not getting the expected value

Tags: java

I have a code snippet about word count:

```
    String[] wordCountArr = {"a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    Stream.of(wordCountArr).collect(TreeMap::new,
            (treeMap, str) -> {

                Object countValue = treeMap.get(str);
                if (countValue != null) {
                    Integer count = Integer.valueOf(countValue.toString());
                    treeMap.put(str, count + 1);
                }
                else {
                    treeMap.put(str, 1);
                }
            }, (treeMap, treeMap2) -> {
                treeMap.putAll(treeMap2);
            }).entrySet()
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

it gets expected value: a=3 b=2 c=2 d=1 e=1, but the Combiner of collect function doesn't seem to executed. And then I got this: [Java 8 Stream - Reduce function's combiner not getting executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910619/java-8-stream-reduce-functions-combiner-not-getting-executed) and change the code to:

```
    Stream.of(wordCountArr).parallel().collect(TreeMap::new,
            (treeMap, str) -> {

                Object countValue = treeMap.get(str);
                if (countValue != null) {
                    Integer count = Integer.valueOf(countValue.toString());
                    treeMap.put(str, count + 1);
                }
                else {
                    treeMap.put(str, 1);
                }
            }, (treeMap, treeMap2) -> {
                treeMap.putAll(treeMap2);
            }).entrySet()
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

but the result is not expected: a=1 b=1 c=1 d=1 e=1, I guess maybe the putAll function just replace old mappings. Any good ideas to get the right result? and Is it more efficient to use parallel stream? Thanks!

Solved:

[What is the best practices to merge two maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335073/what-is-the-best-practices-to-merge-two-maps) replace putAll with merge

Comment: instead of using putAll, you should have a combiner logic. Will have to iterate one of the treeMap, sum if exist and then insert or just insert if the key is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combiner only executed if the framework try to join result of multiple fork when you use parallel stream.

So in the first version, the combiner does not executed.

Your second version of code may lead to ConcurrentModificationException because your TreeMap is not threadsafe when using parallel stream.

One more point is when you combine two Tree, you forgot to sum the value in both trees. You merge all of the content of `treeMap` with `treeMap2` hence the current value in `treeMap` is discarded: `treeMap.putAll(treeMap2);`

You have to manually iterate over keys in `treeMap`, sum the value with `treeMap2` and putback.

I don't know why you come up with this approach, but to count item per group you could simply use `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Long> countMap = Stream.of(wordCountArr).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
           Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have known the way groupingBy. How to make sure a class is threadsafe in java?

Comment: You need to read about thread and concurrency in Java, this topic is too large to talk about here.

Comment: But in case of collection, you have a way to ensure your collection is threadsafe by using Collections.sychronizedXXX(). But this wrapper is not so fast. For Map, there's a `ConcurrentHashMap` with thread-safe and amazing performance

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] wordCountArr = {"a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
Map<String, Long> countMap = Stream.of(wordCountArr).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(letter -> letter, Collectors.counting()));
countMap.forEach((s, count) -> System.out.println(s + " : " + count));
```